# QGIS is flipping my rasters when I vectorize them

Tags: qgis, raster, vectorization

I am using QGIS to vectorize some raster layers.  I was able to do this fine a week ago, but now every time I use the vectorize tool, the resulting vectors are flipped upside down.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you source images without georeferencing, and perhaps in png format?

Comment: The source images are png rasters made in MaxEnt.  I was able to use the polygonize conversion tool to convert them to vectors over the past several weeks, but now they vertically flipped when I polygonize the exact same PNG file.

Comment: Have a try by creating a fake World file for your pngs. Name is by pattern "image_name.wld" and write these values for the 6 lines of the World file: `1 0 0 -1 0 0`.

Comment: Hi - I just tried - I created a World file with the 6 lines you specified.  I saved it as a .pgw file and put it in the same folder as the png.  Tried it again - QGIS is still vertically flipping it when i use the polygonize tool.

Comment: Pity. Could you put some file available for testing? It can be a fake image, all that matters is that others can do exactly the same things as you did and compare the results. Spend a few moments and think what else other people may need to know - QGIS version at least.